# Запятая перед как

Tags: запятые, как

Предложение: Управлением образования, как уполномоченным органом по организации отдыха, оздоровления и занятости детей ()муниципального района, организуется работа по отдыху, оздоровлению и занятости детей и молодежи.
Считаю, что перед как  и после "района" нужна запятая, так как оборот с "как"выступает в значении причины. Управление организует отдых, потому что является уполномоченным органом по организации отдыха. Правильно ли я рассуждаю? Спасибо.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Да, верно: Управлением образования, так как оно является уполномоченным органом по организации отдыха, оздоровления и занятости детей (...) муниципального района, ...

Comment: Спасибо Вам.

Answer (score 0):

> Управлением образования, как уполномоченным органом по организации отдыха, оздоровления и занятости детей ()муниципального района, организуется работа по отдыху, оздоровлению и занятости детей и молодежи.

Очень витиевато. Получается, все дело в работе. Она сама организуется. А Управление как бы ни при чём. Пусть оно поработает: Управление образования как уполномоченный орган по организации отдыха, оздоровления и занятости детей ()муниципального района организует работу по отдыху, оздоровлению и занятости детей и молодежи. Правда, тогда запятая пропадает...

Comment: Не поняла смысла: в качестве? Т.е.поработает органом? Не по-русски.Всё там нормально со смыслом и никакой витиеватости:Управлением образования организуется работа по отдыху, оздоровлению и занятости детей и молодежи.-никак не сама работа организуется, а управлением, потому что оно и должно её организовывать, т. к. является органом по организации отдыха, оздоровления и занятости детей. Орган по организации - корявость, но ведь это деловая речь, она требует терминологической точности

Comment: Согласна с Вами, Людмила. Я запятые ставила.